# web request from one device to another on same local network

Tags: java, spring-boot, local, web-content

I created a spring boot application that serves simple web content. This content is reachable from the same device (192.168.1.10) using "localhost:8080/greeting", but I can not access this content from another device (192.168.1.15) on the same local network (at home).
 - I googled on the web a lot but can't find a proper solution.
 - I allowed firewalls for all app, all ports and all protocols on each device.
 But doesn't work. What is needed?

Comment: what url you are using to hit the server from another machine ? What is the error code ? 404 ?

Comment: the url that I hit is: http://192.168.1.10:8080/greeting
not 404 or other error code. I tried to get the page via postman, result is the same: "Could not get any response".

Comment: what do I not know is, should I make some settings embedded tomcat server, or on code, or on windows components (like on WiFi adapter), or on router at home (like port forwarding), or is it just a firewall issue??